# Выражение "стена объявлений" появилось в языке до Вконтакте или после?

Tags: семантика, история, жаргон

Гугл находит 300 тыс. ссылок по запросу "**стена объявлений**" и миллион по запросу "**доска объявлений**". Я живу в Ставрополе и никогда не слышал, чтобы доски объявлений называли стенами. Это какая-то диалектная форма или это влияние на язык жаргона соцсети Вконтакте?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Да, "стена" или "стенка" - это термин социальных сетей. Это не совсем синоним доски объявлений. "Стена" обычно принадлежит одному участнику (редко группе) и на ней отражаются всякие события из жизни хозяина, часто даже без всякой инициативы с его стороны. Далеко не всегда записи на стене можно отнести к объявлениям. Это вы, наверное, знаете.

Но тот же функционал и интерфейс можно использовать и для создания "стены", профилированной именно под объявления. Таким образом получится нечто, что можно назвать "стеной объявлений". Поскольку для конечного пользователя большой разницы между "доской" и "стеной объявлений" нет, доску объявлений (с ограниченным доступом) начинают называть "стеной" независимо от функционального наполнения. Думаю, что это не критично. Ну хочется говорить "стена", а не "доска" - ну пусть будет стена. Тем более, что принцип организации и содержание стены может сильно различаться от сообщества к сообществу и от сети к сети.

Что было раньше, яйцо или курица, сказать не могу.

Comment: Вообще-то по закону нельзя клеить объявления на стены, для этого существуют специальные доски. Если до появления Вконтакта не было выражения "стена объявлений", то тогда получается, что стены Вконтакта названы в честь стены Цоя, потому, что до появления Вконтакта стена Цоя была единственной стеной на которой писали объявления и прочие месседжи.

Comment: Послушайте, при чем тут закон? Это ж не стена жилого дома, это место специально отведенно В Европе создают стены именно для того, чтобы на них можно было писать, оставлять автографы - и т. д. Отсюда и появились стены в соцсетях. Я не думаю, что стена Цоя была первой в мире. Стремление разрисовать вертикальную поверхность было известно еще неандертальцам.

Comment: Я вам повторяю, что я никогда не слышал в живой речи выражение "стена объявлений", и оно не могло возникнуть просто так поскольку клеить объявления на стены запрещено. Но мне френд в ФБ написал, что в Москве, на Банной, была какая-то стена объявлений еще в 1970 году. Вы когда-нибудь встречали в литературе выражение "стена объявлений"? Если оно и использовалось то как диалектное. Но даже если в диалектах использовались "стены объявлений", то на них не писали, а клеили объявления. Писали только на стене Цоя.

Comment: Хаха, против выражения "стена объявлений" возражаете, а слово "френд" выдумали. Как-то непоследовательно!

Comment: Я не выступаю против выражения "стена объявлений", я только пытаюсь обосновать происхождение "стен" вконтакте от стены Цоя на Арбате.